# How to break line in iOS email

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, ipad, email

I want to break line on "mailto" tag. Here is my code in C#

```
mailto:aaa@gmail.com?subject=My subject&body=I want break in here.%0D%0A Line2 content
```

I am using "%0D%0A" to break line. In my browser, this code is worked. But in Email application of iPad, it can't break line. Help me plz

Comment: you are programming in C#?

Answer (score 0):

IF you mean Objective C and Using `MFMailComposeViewController`
You can use something like this

```
NSString *emailBody = @"<HTML><BODY><B>It is raining in sunny California!</B><br>this is my second line</BODY></HTML>";
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
```

Comment: No, it is C#, help me plz

Comment: I dont think so. It's not allow HTML

Comment: did you try by adding tags of html to your string. try it don't assume, there should be a way, and HTML is providing this..

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) sendEventInEmail
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    NSArray *toRecipent=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"aaa@gmail.com", nil];
    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipents];

    NSString *emailSubject = @"My subject";

    [picker setSubject:emailSubject];

    // Fill out the email body text

    NSString *emailBody = @"1st line<br />2nd line<br />3rd line<br />and so on..."

    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

    picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

Comment: in this case, I'm buil a link to tag a. And i don't think it is solution

Comment: you mention in your question title IOS email so i provide solution for ios for sending mail.

Comment: For C# this link is helpful for you http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/46752/unity-3-sending-email-with-c.html


http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/358635/how-do-i-send-an-email-on-ios-using-applicationope.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSMutableString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> <head><h3>User Detail </h3></head> <body> <table border=0> <tr><td> First Name:<td><font color=color:red> %@ </font></td> </td></tr>  <tr><td>Last Name: <td><font color=color:red> %@ </font></td></td></tr> <tr><td>User Name: <td><font color=color:red> %@ </font></td></td></tr>  <tr><td> Password: <td><font color=color:red>%@</font></td> </td></tr>  <tr><td> Birth Date: <td><font color=color:red>%@</font></td> </td></tr> <tr><td> Location: <td><font color=color:red>%@</font></td> </td></tr> <tr><td>Image :</td></tr></table></body></html> ",msgDataFName,msgDataLName,msgDataUserName,msgDataPswd,msgDataBdate,msgDataLocation];
```

it's a whole body of email using html tag......

Comment: in this case, I'm buil a link to tag a. And i don't think it is solution